# Delphi Webmodule : What happened to TWebModuleList?

Tags: delphi, isapi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, webbroker

My program is a Delphi ISAPI DLL built with Delphi 2007. 
I'm migrating to Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and TWebModuleList is gone from Web.WebReq.

With D2007, when the application starts, the following code is called in order to pre instanciate a pool of 5 WebModules.

```
procedure TSWebApplication.CreationWebModules;
var
  i: integer;
  TabDataModules : array of TWebModuleList;
begin

  SetLength(TabDataModules,1);
  TabDataModules[0] := ActivateWebModules;
  if Assigned(TabDataModules[0]) then
    TabDataModules[0].AutoCreateModules;

  SetLength(TabDataModules, NbInstances);

  for i := 1 to NbInstances - 1 do
  begin
    TabDataModules[i] := ActivateWebModules;
    if Assigned(TabDataModules[i]) then
      TabDataModules[i].AutoCreateModules;
  end;

  for i := 0 to NbInstances - 1 do
    DeActivateWebModules(TabDataModules[i]);
end;
```

This way, instead of having the (first 5) WebModules created on demand, they are created when the application starts, then deactivated and auto activated on demand.

I know WebModules are managed by IIS and we don't necessary need this behavior, but it is the way it worked (pretty well).

TWebModuleList seems gone since Delphi XE8 (no page on docwiki.embarcadero.com whereas it was still there on the XE7 site).
I couldn't find ANY changelog, or other information on why it is gone et how we can build the same behavior...

Does anyone have any information?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't exist in any of the source files in the Pro SKUs of Seattle or Berlin (don't have Tokyo installed on this box), so apparently it was either removed entirely or moved into a higher SKU. A quick check in D2007 shows it was in the WebReq.pas unit, and a review of the Berlin version of that unit does not include it at all. As to why it was removed, you'd have to contact EMBT and ask them; they'd be the ones to have removed it, and we're not them. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite:  Fwiw, what you say is also the case in the Ent. versions of Seattle and Tokyo.  I wonder if TWebModuleList went awol in the changes/rearrangements made in Datasnap etc  ...

Comment: @MartynA: Yep, that would seem to confirm that it was intentionally removed. I'm not sure why, though.

Comment: Thanks I've asked on google+ and tagged Marco Cantu. I think it went with a redesign but it isn't documented at all